# Hibernate, xml mapping issue

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jsp

this is my first application using hibernate ,in this program i have a jsp file while click submit button its call SaveServlet.java , and it get the values from text box , but while run the project it shows error, some one please help me .

```
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "hibernate-mapping" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "default-cascade" must be declared for element type "hibernate-mapping".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "default-access" must be declared for element type "hibernate-mapping".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "default-lazy" must be declared for element type "hibernate-mapping".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "auto-import" must be declared for element type "hibernate-mapping".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "class" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "table" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "mutable" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "polymorphism" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "dynamic-update" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "dynamic-insert" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "select-before-update" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "optimistic-lock" must be declared for element type "class".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "id" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "id".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "id".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "id".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "generator" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "class" must be declared for element type "generator".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "property" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "unique" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "optimistic-lock" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "lazy" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "generated" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "property" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "unique" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "optimistic-lock" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "lazy" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "generated" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "property" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "unique" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "optimistic-lock" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "lazy" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "generated" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "property" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "unique" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "optimistic-lock" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "lazy" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "generated" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Element type "property" must be declared.
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "name" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "column" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "type" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "unique" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "optimistic-lock" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "lazy" must be declared for element type "property".
ERROR:   HHH000196: Error parsing XML (40) : Attribute "generated" must be declared for element type "property".
" Error in SaveServlet  org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML"
```

persistent class User.java

```
import com.hiber.Bean
public class User {
     private int id;
    private String username,password,email,phone,city;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

and this mapping file user.hbm

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="user">
        <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="username" column="username" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property name="password" column="password" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property name="email" column="email" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property name="phone" column="phone" type="java.lang.String"></property>
        <property name="city" column="city" type="java.lang.String"></property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is configuration file hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brinkle?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <mapping resource="com/hiber/Bean/User.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Dao class file UserDao.java

```
package com.hiber.Dao

public class UserDao {
    Session session=NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        Transaction tran=session.beginTransaction();
         public void addUser(String username,String password,String email,String phone,String city)
         {
        User user=new User();


        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPhone(phone);
        user.setCity(city);

        session.save(user);
        tran.commit();

        System.out.println("saved succesfully");

}
}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
public class NewHibernateUtil {

    private static  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
   {
       if (sessionFactory == null) {
            // loads configuration and mappings
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

            // builds a session factory from the service registry
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);           
        }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("Session not created..........");
       }

        return sessionFactory;

}
}
```

this is my servlet SaveServlet.java

```
 package com.hiber.Controller;
    import com.hiber.dao.*;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.hibernate.HibernateException;


    public class SaveServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
           String username=request.getParameter("username");
            String password =request.getParameter("password");
            String email=request.getParameter("email");
            String phone=request.getParameter("phone");
            String city =request.getParameter("city");
            System.out.println("the name is "+username+"pass is  "+password+" emial is "+email +" phone is "+phone +" and city is "+city);
            try
            {
    //            System.out.println("here we go");
              UserDao ud=new UserDao();
              ud.addUser(username, password, email, phone, city);
              RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("welcomeJSF.jsp");
              rd.forward(request, response);
             // response.sendRedirect("welcomeJSF.jsp");
            }
            catch(HibernateException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error in SaveServlet  "+e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you leave out the first few lines in the `.cfg.xml` and `hbm.xml` files, or is that all you have?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">   These lines?

Comment: Yes, can you update your question with the full code you are using? Those headers are important.

Comment: now my code is same as below which was posted by someone,last one

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the header of the hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

And put this in the header of the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: added this and made some other changes also , now i got " Error in SaveServlet  org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml" only this error

Answer (score 0):

User.hbm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <!-- Generated May 18, 2017 3:31:25 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="com.hiber.Bean.User" table="USERData">
            <id name="id" type="int">
                <column name="ID" />
                <generator class="increment" />
            </id>
            <property name="username" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="USERNAME" />
            </property>
            <property name="password" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="PASSWORD" />
            </property>
            <property name="email" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="EMAIL" />
            </property>
            <property name="phone" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="PHONE" />
            </property>
            <property name="city" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="CITY" />
            </property>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://<host><:port>/<database></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">databasename</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <mapping resource="com/hiber/Bean/User.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

SaveServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       String username=request.getParameter("username");
        String password =request.getParameter("password");
        String email=request.getParameter("email");
        String phone=request.getParameter("phone");
        String city =request.getParameter("city");
        System.out.println("the name is "+username+"pass is  "+password+" emial is "+email +" phone is "+phone +" and city is "+city);
        try
        {
//            System.out.println("here we go");
          UserDao ud=new UserDao();
         ud.get();
          ud.addUser(username, password, email, phone, city);
         response.sendRedirect("welcomeJSF.jsp");
        }
        catch(HibernateException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in SaveServlet  "+e);
        }
```

UserDao.java

```
package com.hiber.Bean;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class UserDao {
    Session session;
    Transaction tran;
    public void get(){
    Configuration c=new Configuration();
    c.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory se=c.buildSessionFactory();
     session=se.openSession();
         tran=session.beginTransaction();

    }
         public void addUser(String username,String password,String email,String phone,String city)
         {
        User user=new User();


        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPhone(phone);
        user.setCity(city);

        session.save(user);
        tran.commit();

        System.out.println("saved succesfully");

}
         }
```

Comment: thank you for this , while i run this code i got a error like 'Error in SaveServlet  org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml'